# indent code correctly in Github list item in README.md

Tags: github, readme

I'm creating `README.md` file for my Repo in github, but i cant indent the **code blocks** as much as my **list items** has indent from the left, I'm trying as **bottom** and i want this block of code to start with indention of **list items**.

````
* list
  * Item one
  * ``` codes here..```
````

also it didn't worked :( don't know why.

> Skip a line and indent eight spaces. Eight spaces will trigger the code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add blank lines to make it work with the 8 spaces. Now because your `item one` is already 4 spaces in you need to add 12 spaces (4 + 8 = 12) like so

```
* list
    * item one

            codes here..
```

Which will then look like:

- list

  - item one

    ```
      codes here..
    ```

Answer (score 2):

- List

  - Item one
  - ```
    This is
    a code block
    I had to manually indent these lines
    ```
  - Item three

The above is the output of

````
 * List
    * Item one
    * ```
      This is
      a code block
      I had to manually indent these lines
      ```
    * Item three
````

Does this help?